# Can you delete rows in Python with openpyxl by setting all cell values in a row to 'None'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl to attempt to delete rows from a spreadsheet. I understand that there is a funciton specifically for deleting rows, however, I was trying to overcome this problem without knowledge of that function, and I am now wondering why my method does not work.

To simplify the problem, I set up a spreadsheet and filled it with letters in some of the cells. In this case, the first `print(sheet.max_row)` printed "9". After setting all the cell values to `None`, I expected the number of rows to be 0, however, the second print statement printed "9" again.

Is it possible to reduce the row count by setting all the cells in a row to None?

```py
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter, column_index_from_string

spreadsheet = load_workbook(filename = pathToSpreadsheet) #pathToSpreadsheet represents the absolute path I had to the spreadsheet that I created. 
sheet = spreadsheet.active

print(sheet.max_row) # Printed "9".
rowCount = sheet.max_row
columnCount = sheet.max_column
finalBoundary = get_column_letter(columnCount) + str(rowCount)

allCellObjects = sheet["A1":finalBoundary]

for rowOfCells in allCellObjects:
    for cell in rowOfCells:
        cell.value = None

print(sheet.max_row) # Also printed "9".
```

Thank you for your time and effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer NO.
However, you could access the cell from the sheet with the cell coordinates and delete them.

```
for rowOfCells in allCellObjects:
    for cell in rowOfCells:
        del sheet[cell.coordinate]

print(sheet.max_row)
```

---

A little more elaborate answer would be that a worksheet in Openpyxl stores it's `_cells` as a `dict` with coordinates as key. `max_row` property is defined

```py
@property
def max_row(self):
    """The maximum row index containing data (1-based)

    :type: int
    """
    max_row = 1
    if self._cells:
        rows = set(c[0] for c in self._cells)
        max_row = max(rows)
    return max_row
```

So if the cells was None, the keys/coordinates would still prevail eg: `_cells = {(1,1):None, (1,2):None, (5,4): None}`.
`max_row`would then still give us the biggest y-component of the key.